# Error: expression must be a modifiable lvalue (tal * tal)

Tags: c, lvalue

So here is my problem:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

int kvad(int tal) {
    int sum;
    tal * tal = sum; /* The left "tal" has the error: Expression must be a modifiable lvalue*/
    return sum;
}

int kub(int alt) {
    int pro;
    alt * alt * alt = pro; /* The left "alt" has the error: Expression must be a modifiable lvalue*/
    return pro;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int ggr, gda, tre, tva;
    printf("Hur många tal att multiplicera: ");
    scanf_s("%d", ggr);
    printf("\n i   i * i   i * i * i\n=== ======= ===========\n");
    for (gda = 1; gda <= ggr; gda++) {
        tva = kvad(gda);
        tre = kub(gda);
        printf("%2d%6d%10d\n", gda, tva, tre);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I do not know if the last part is needed but I am not sure so I did include it anyway.

I know that there are other threads with similar problems but I can't find the solution there.

Comment: What did you expect `tal * tal = sum;` to do?

Comment: I expected to output the product of a number multiplicated by it self.

Comment: An assignment doesn't produce output, it stores a value in a variable. Did you expect the result of `tal * tal` to be stored in `sum`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `lvalue` is a value that can be assigned to, and if often a variable. By contrast, an `rvalue` is a value that cannot be assigned to. The names come from the trend that `lvalue`s tend to appear on the left side of an assignment, whereas `rvalue`s tend to appear on the right side of an assignment. In your code, you have:

```
tal * tal = sum;
```

Which is an error because `tal * tal` yields a value that can't be assigned to. The expression results in a number, but this is different from a variable because it doesn't make sense to assign a number to another number. It would be like saying `5 = variable`.

Also remember that assignment is non commutative. That is, `tal * tal = sum` is not equivalent to `sum = tal * tal`. The name on the left of the `=` is what will be assigned the value on the right, so the name on the left must always be something that can be assigned to, that is, an `lvalue`.

Comment: These are often-used definitions of lvalue and rvalue. It may be noteworthy, that the C standard uses different definitions: What's called an rvalue here is called the "_value_ of an expression" in the standard; and (C11 6.3.2) "an lvalue is an expression with an object type or an incomplete type other than `void`", which, for example, also covers array identifiers although they cannot be on the left-hand-side of an assignment (they aren't _modifiable lvalues_ in the terms of the standard).

Comment: @mafso: Actually the C11 definition of "lvalue" is "an expression (with an object type other than void) that potentially designates an object". The meaning of "potentially designates" is a bit vague; the idea is that `*ptr` is an lvalue regardless of the current value of `ptr`. The "that potentially designates an object" wording was added in C11. The 3 ISO C standards (1990, 1999, and 2011) all have subtly different definitions of "lvalue"; it's notoriously hard to get right.

Comment: @KeithThompson: Thanks a lot, I've copied from the wrong draft, quoting wrongly definitely shouldn't happen. Btw, do you know the reasons for the change?

Comment: @mafso: As it happens, yes, I do. The C99 definition (which attempted to correct a problem with the C90 definition) was "An *lvalue* is an expression with an object type or an incomplete type other than ***`void`***; if an lvalue does not designate an object when it is evaluated, the behavior is undefined." Taken literally, this would imply that `42` is an value, and that evaluating `42` causes undefined behavior -- clearly not the intent.

Comment: C90 had said that an lvalue is "an expression ... that designates an object", which implies that `*ptr` is an value if and only if `ptr` happens to be valid and non-null. The C99 definition attempted to fix that, but inadvertently dropped the requirement that it designates an object (which is the whole point of the concept. The change in C11 was made in response to a suggestion I had made on the comp.std.c newsgroup. (I'm not entirely happy with the vagueness of "potentially designates"; I suspect that "lvalue" *could* be defined almost entirely syntactically.)

Answer (score 1):

You have to put the variable that receives a new value on the left side of the `=`

```
sum = tal * tal;
pro = alt * alt * alt;
```